# On the cardinality of the set $ A(m) := \{ (a, b) \in \mathbb{N}^2 : \; N \leq a \leq 2 N, \; a^2 - b^2 = m \}, $

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, additive-combinatorics

Question: Consider the set
  $$ A(m) := \{ (a, b) \in \mathbb{N}^2 : \;  N \leq a \leq 2 N, \;  a^2 - b^2 = m  \}, $$
where $ \mathbb{Z} \ni m < 0$ and  $N \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{ 0 \}$.  Then 
$$ \sup_{ \mathbb{Z} \ni m < 0} (\sharp A(m)) = O(N^{\epsilon}) \; \mbox{ for all } \epsilon > 0 \; ? $$

Remark: My failed tentative was to use the following result concerning
to divisor bounds of a natural number:
$$ \sharp B(\ell) : = \sharp \{ (c, d) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 : |c | \leq 2 N, |d| \leq 2 N \mbox{ and }  c \cdot d = \ell \} = O(N^{\epsilon}),$$
but, in the above case we not have information about the localization of $b \in \mathbb N$. I am very gratefull for any suggestion !